# Is it possible to use pushViewController without a navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've got a UISearchBar in my view, and when the results button is pressed I'd like it to load in a new view. Is this possible without using a navigation controller?

I'm new to iPhone development so not entirely sure if moving between views is solely reliable on a navigation controller or not. From all the examples I've seen using pushViewController, it seems to look that way. Hoping I'm proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController provides the simplest way to manage a stack of view controllers, but it's not necessary by any means; you can move your views around, and add and remove them from the hierarchy, however you like. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do, and why you want to avoid using a navigation controller?

Comment: I've got a tabbar application, and when it launches the initial view contains only a UISearchBar. The goal is so when the user enters a search term and hits return, a new view will be loaded. From what I gather, the navigation controller works in conjunction with a navigation bar (am I right in saying that?) ... and I don't particular want a navigation bar in the UI.